# Microsoft Graph Subscriptions - Method not Allowed

Tags: office365api, microsoft-graph-api

I am currently trying to send a request to create a subscription to messages using the Microsoft Graph API, but am getting an error 405 Method Not Allowed.

I was wondering if anyone had an idea why this was happening?

Here is the request I send:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/subscriptions
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 208

{
   "changeType": "Created",
   "notificationUrl":"https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",
   "clientState": "subscription-identifier",  
   "resource": "me/messages"
}
```

and then here is the response:

```
{
 "error": {
  "code": "MethodNotAllowed",
  "message": "Method not allowed.",
  "innerError": {
   "request-id": "a61ece92-7b7f-4693-b047-80c419ebde23",
   "date": "2016-01-06T11:13:02"
  } 
 }
}
```

Response Headers:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin → *
Allow → GET
Cache-Control → private
Content-Type → application/json
Date → Wed, 06 Jan 2016 11:13:02 GMT
Duration → 58.558
OutBoundDuration → 0
Server → Microsoft-IIS/8.5
Transfer-Encoding → chunked
X-Powered-By → ASP.NET
client-request-id → a61ece92-7b7f-4693-b047-80c419ebde23
request-id → a61ece92-7b7f-4693-b047-80c419ebde23
x-ms-ags-diagnostic → {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"NorthEurope","Slice":"SliceB","ScaleUnit":"001","Host":"AGSFE_IN_4","ADSiteName":"DUB"}}
```

Comment: Could you please share the response headers returned for your request? I wasn't able to reproduce that behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The subscriptions entity set/functionality is currently only accessible to Azure Active Directory users. Your request was sent with a Microsoft Account (Live Id) access token and we don't currently support subscriptions for such accounts.

Comment: Do you know when such accounts will be supported roughly?

Comment: There is no firm ETA, but my rough estimate would be spring.