# Microsoft Graph Subscriptions - Exchange Online resources are not supported for MSA requests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I think I have sort of the same problem as [Microsoft Graph Subscriptions - Method not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439663/microsoft-graph-subscriptions-method-not-allowed) and the question is answered and there is this comment [Microsoft Graph Subscriptions - Method not Allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439663/microsoft-graph-subscriptions-method-not-allowed#comment57120925_34663855)

Request `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions`

```
{
   "changeType": "created,updated,deleted",
   "notificationUrl":"https://c5e719ba.ngrok.io/api/ms/watch",
   "resource": "me/events",
    "expirationDateTime":"2016-12-07T02:23:45.9356913Z",
}
```

Response Header

```
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/json
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
request-id: 9bd7a103-5ec0-4ed5-b20d-f8fb4cc75b88
client-request-id: 9bd7a103-5ec0-4ed5-b20d-f8fb4cc75b88
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"North Europe","Slice":"SliceA","ScaleUnit":"000","Host":"AGSFE_IN_4","ADSiteName":"DUB"}}
Duration: 261.5354
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 06 Dec 2016 23:11:45 GMT
```

Response

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "",
        "message": "Exchange Online resources are not supported for MSA requests.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "9bd7a103-5ec0-4ed5-b20d-f8fb4cc75b88",
            "date": "2016-12-06T23:11:46"
        }
    }
}
```

But I'm not sure what should I do to make it work, I'm not using azure, but it seems that if I use [Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-faqs) it should work, if this is what I really must do I think it's a hassle not being able to use all the `microsoftgraph` without using an azure service. (I can live without getting the [profile photo `This operation in version 1.0 supports only a user's work or school mailboxes and not personal mailboxes.`](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/profilephoto_get)).

I don't have an office365 account so I don't know if this won't be a problem if the user that uses my application sign in with an office 365 account.. because if it works with a home/commercial account I could verify if the account it's from MSA or home/commercial as a workaround I could do something like this https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android/issues/26 and if I know that it's an MSA account I could ask the user to use another account in order to use the app...

So the question is: in order to make it work with a MSA (live) account do I've to use `Azure Active Directory B2C`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Subscriptions for MSA (Live accounts) can now be created on the graph "beta" version for "me/messages" and "me/contacts".

We also support such MSA/live subscriptions for OneDrive resources like "me/drive/root".

Comment: So, if the user that signup with a Work or School account, me/contacts and subscriptions to me/events are available? I'll have to check something like this (https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android/issues/26) if the user is MSA or not.... thanks

Comment: @jjchiw Yes, if they sign up with work or school, those resources are available. You will need to make a determination if the account is work or school.

Comment: Just to other who gets error 'Specified resource is not supported for MSA requests.' it means you can't use regular MS Account, you have to get Office 365 Paid Account.

Comment: So... MSA is supposed to stand for live.com accounts?  Which I guess is the same as Outlook.com and Office365 Home accounts?  Microsoft has the most cryptic and bs error messages and requirements.  Doing a simple oauth integration has been like performing a ritual to revive the dark lord zenu.