# Microsoft.Graph Subscriptions - Exchange Online resources are not supported for MSA requests

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to write a service to take an action when a calendar event occurs. ie Appoint due in 15 min warning. Multiple users will need to be able to register with the service. I think Subscriptions are the what I need, although what "ChageType" to use to get an alert, I have not gotten to yet. Right now I get **"Exchange Online resources are not supported for MSA requests."** when I try to use this code. I am working against an outlook.com account.

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = SDKHelper.GetAuthenticatedClient();

var subscription = new Microsoft.Graph.Subscription();
subscription.ChangeType = "updated";
subscription.ExpirationDateTime = System.DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1);
subscription.ClientState = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
subscription.NotificationUrl = "https://mywebhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient"; // must be valid and able to verify?

subscription.Resource = "me/events";
var newsub = await graphClient.Subscriptions
                     .Request().AddAsync(subscription);
```

Answer (score 0):

Subscriptions to **Outlook.com** ARE supported by the nugget package: [Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0/) 
that wraps the Outlook365 API.

[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/notify-rest-operations](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0/)

I got it working -- sort of using:
https://github.com/jasonjoh/dotnet-tutorial
combined with:
[aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/aspnet-webhooks-rest-sample#ngrok)

So far I can create a subscription using an MVC App and capture User Info + Client State; at the webhook I can capture client state and subscription id along with a Change Type and Resource ID:

```
https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/Users('0003bffd-a898-60b1-0000-000000000000@84df9e7f-e9f6-40af-b435-aaaaaaaaaaaa')/Messages('AQMkADAwATNiZmYAZC1hODk4LTYwYjEtMDACLTAwCgBGAAADhL94GyFZe0WMH6_2kacBNAcAVYqcEoTpoEy-bsETzU244wAAAgEKAAAAVYqcEoTpoEy-bsETzU244wAAAFP_o9AAAAA=')
```

Unfortunately, no information about the "item" is provided.

Update: using info from  [MVC 5 application - implement OAuth Authorization code flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845420/mvc-5-application-implement-oauth-authorization-code-flow) I am able to get "Authorization Code Flow" working - still need to figure out how to Authenticate OWIN (so the MVC app has a Logon Identity) using an access_token.

Answer (score -1):

It is currently not supported to use MS accounts for subscriptions on several resources. Instead the mailbox must use a "work or school" account.

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41026203/270142 for further details.

Comment: Subscriptions to Outlook.com ARE supported by the nugget package: Microsoft.Office365.OutlookServices-V2.0 that wraps the Outlook365 API.  actually have this working in pieces -- the authentication model is like pulling teeth with an ice skate.